# spark create Dataframe in UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a example, want to create Dataframe in a UDF. Something like the one below

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
```

data to Dataframe

```
    val df = Seq((1,1,34,23,34,56),(2,1,56,34,56,23),(3,0,34,23,23,78),(4,0,23,34,78,23),(5,1,56,23,23,12),
(6,1,67,34,56,34),(7,0,23,23,23,56),(8,0,12,34,45,89),(9,1,12,34,12,34),(10,0,12,34,23,34)).toDF("id","label","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4")
    val assemblerDF = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("tag1", "tag2", "tag3","tag4")).setOutputCol("features")
    val data = assemblerDF.transform(df)
    val Array(train,test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
    val testData=test.toDF    

    val loadmodel=LogisticRegressionModel.load("/user/xu/savemodel")
    sc.broadcast(loadmodel)
    val assemblerFe = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("a", "b", "c","d")).setOutputCol("features")
    sc.broadcast(assemblerFe)
```

UDF

```
    def predict(predictSet:Vector):Double={
        val set=Seq((1,2,3,4)).toDF("a","b","c","d")
        val predata = assemblerFe.transform(set)
        val result=loadmodel.transform(predata)
        result.rdd.take(1)(0)(3).toString.toDouble}

    spark.udf.register("predict", predict _)
    testData.registerTempTable("datatable")
    spark.sql("SELECT predict(features) FROM datatable").take(1)
```

i get an error like

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7) [Executor task launch worker for task 7]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
```

and

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double)
```

Is dataframe not supported? I am using Spark 2.3.0 and Scala 2.11. thanks

Comment: Why do you want to apply your model on test data in UDF, you can just apply the model to the test data in main program.

Comment: base on the previous framework,maybe cann't create Dataframe in UDF

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you don't need UDF here to apply the Trained model to test data. You can apply the model to test dataframe in the main program itself as below:

```
val df = Seq((1,1,34,23,34,56),(2,1,56,34,56,23),(3,0,34,23,23,78),(4,0,23,34,78,23),(5,1,56,23,23,12),
(6,1,67,34,56,34),(7,0,23,23,23,56),(8,0,12,34,45,89),(9,1,12,34,12,34),(10,0,12,34,23,34)).toDF("id","label","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4")
val assemblerDF = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("tag1", "tag2", "tag3","tag4")).setOutputCol("features")
val data = assemblerDF.transform(df)
val Array(train,test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val testData=test.toDF    

val loadmodel=LogisticRegressionModel.load("/user/xu/savemodel")
sc.broadcast(loadmodel)
val assemblerFe = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("a", "b", "c","d")).setOutputCol("features")
sc.broadcast(assemblerFe)


val set=Seq((1,2,3,4)).toDF("a","b","c","d")
val predata = assemblerFe.transform(set)
val result=loadmodel.transform(predata) // Applying model on predata dataframe. You can apply model on any DataFrame.
```

result is a DataFrame now, you can Reigister the DataFrame as a table and query predictionLabel and features using SQL OR you can directly select the predictLabel and other fields from DataFrame.

Please note, UDF is a feature of Spark SQL to define new Column-based functions that extend the vocabulary of Spark SQL’s DSL for transforming Datasets. It doesnt return the DataFrame itself as a return type. and generally its not advised to use UDF's unless necessary, refer to: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs-blackbox.html